# Prepros - Conflict version sass when using custom Ruby path

Tags: ruby, susy-sass, prepros

I try to follow [this instruction](https://github.com/ShamilS/Prepros-Docs/blob/susy_and_compass/contents/sass-compass-susy.md), and after all is done, I am gettin this error when using prepros to compile the `scss` file.

```
Gem::LoadError on line ["1638"] of C: Unable to activate susy-2.1.1, because sass-3.2.19 conflicts with sass (~> 3.3.0)
Run with --trace to see the full backtrace
```

Please help me solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, sorry for my bad in English.

I found out my answer is just go to the Ruby installation directory, my own is:

```
C:\Ruby193\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems
```

And I found something like this.

http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-vM3dMbk-UoY/U04e50qvcEI/AAAAAAAABKU/m3I4LNANEvw/s1600/ruby-gems.png

Sorry because I don't enough reputation. I delete the susy-2.0.0.rc.1 folder. And pick an older version of susy.

Go to [this link](https://rubygems.org/gems/susy/versions) to get the Susy version you want to install it in Ruby. And I choose randomly the version using command

> gem install susy -v 1.0.2

I get this errors

> error screen.scss (Line 12 of _susy.scss: Undefined mixin
>   'with-only-support-for'.) overwrite css/screen.css

And several errors like this link

> stackoverflow.com/questions/16449160/mixin-container-takes-0-arguments-but-2-were-passed

And all of this errors start from the version of Susy.

Finally, I choose the version susy -v 1.0.9. And it work for me.

You can use the command in Ruby command line to check all of gems version

> gem list

And this is my list infor:
C:\Windows\System32>gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

> bigdecimal (1.1.0) chunky_png (1.3.0) compass (0.12.5) fssm (0.2.10)
>   io-console (0.3) json (1.5.5) minitest (2.5.1) rake (0.9.2.2) rdoc
>   (3.9.5) sass (3.3.4, 3.2.19) sassy-buttons (0.2.6) susy (2.1.1,
>   2.0.0.rc.1, 2.0.0.alpha.4, 1.0.9, 1.0.2)